# Does JavaScript Promise.allSettled have a callback?

Tags: javascript, promise

Does JavaScript Promise.allSettled have a callback when all settled?

I need to call a function after `promise.allSettled`.

Comment: It returns a promise, so you can still sue the Promise API

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Did you do some [research](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Promise.allSettled` returns a Promise, so just like any other Promise, call `.then` on it:

```
Promise.allSettled(arrOfPromises)
  .then((result) => {
    // all Promises are settled
  });
```